Next.js middleware not executing as it should on production
I recently migrated my project from Next.js 14's pages router to the app router. We are utilizing two different layouts, so our app directory looks something like this:
|-- app
|--- (main)
|---- layout.tsx
|---- page.tsx
|--- (auth)
|---- layout.tsx
|---- page.tsx
|--- layout.tsx

As I am using the src folder, the middleware resides inside src/middleware, which is the same directory as the app (src/app). However, the middleware is not executing as expected in production, although it functions properly locally.
So, to be clear:
If the user is not authenticated, they should be redirected to /auth and should never go to /
if the user is authenticated, then they should not be able to see /auth page but /
basically, the middleware is not "checking" some pages, so sometimes when I am not authenticated I am able to go to / and vice versa.
Middleware:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

const protectedRoutes = ['/']
const publicRoutes = ['/auth']

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const path = req.nextUrl.pathname

  const isProtectedRoute = protectedRoutes.includes(path)
  const isPublicRoute = publicRoutes.includes(path)

  const cookie = cookies().get('token')?.value

  // const session = await decrypt(cookie)

  if (isProtectedRoute && !cookie) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/auth', req.nextUrl))
  }

  if (isPublicRoute && !!cookie) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', req.nextUrl))
  }

  return NextResponse.next()
}

// Routes Middleware should not run on
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)'],
}

Ah, I have src/middleware.ts and src/app in the file tree.

The dir should be auth not (auth)

did you fix it? having the same issue
